# Calculating desired value based on data table

Tags: vba, excel, scientific-computing

I have a data table of volumes and total concentration. I want to input a value into a cell, and loop through the data table and output the total volume needed from the data table to calculate my new mixture.

Example data table:

```
sample #    Volume  concentration
1            4000.0    250000
2            4000.0    300000
3            4000.0    650000
4            4000.0    2000000
```

If this is my data, and I want to make a new batch that is 8000 volume and 700,000 for concentration, how can I calculate which sample numbers to mix and in what volumes to get the new concentration and volume.

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for is more of an algorithm than help with specific code.  Do you have an equation/formula you would use to calculate the desired answer?

Comment: If you are just looking for a way to find a solution, the Solver Add-In would be much easier than coding it in VBA.  I'd suggest looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume formula should be as follows:

[image: dilution formula]

Consider the algorithm implemented with the below VBA code, place the code in the `Sheet1` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Solution
    Volume As Variant
    Initial As Variant
    Conc As Variant
End Type

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Samples() As Solution
    Dim ConcTarget As Double
    Dim ConcMin As Double
    Dim ConcMax As Double
    Dim ConcDelta As Double
    Dim ConcDelta1 As Double
    Dim ConcDelta2 As Double
    Dim VolumeTarget As Double
    Dim VolumeTotal As Double
    Dim VolumeMix As Double
    Dim Volume1 As Double
    Dim Volume2 As Double
    Dim Sample1 As Long
    Dim Sample2 As Long
    Dim Sample1Found As Boolean
    Dim Sample2Found As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' retrieve initial data and targets from the sheet and clear results
    i = 2
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Do While .Cells(i, 1) <> ""
            ReDim Preserve Samples(i - 2)
            Samples(i - 2).Volume = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            Samples(i - 2).Initial = Samples(i - 2).Volume
            Samples(i - 2).Conc = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = ""
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        ConcTarget = .Cells(2, 7).Value
        VolumeTarget = .Cells(2, 6).Value
    End With

    VolumeTotal = 0
    ' begin of iterations
    Do

        ' min and max concentration available
        ConcMax = 0
        ConcMin = 1.7976931348623E+308
        For i = 0 To UBound(Samples)
            If Samples(i).Conc < ConcMin And Samples(i).Volume > 0 Then
                ConcMin = Samples(i).Conc
                Sample1 = i ' lowest concentration sample
            End If
            If Samples(i).Conc > ConcMax And Samples(i).Volume > 0 Then
                ConcMax = Samples(i).Conc
                Sample2 = i ' highest concentration sample
            End If
        Next

        If ConcMin > 0 Then
            ' zero concentration sample isn't available
            ' choose appropriate samples available to mix
            Sample1Found = False
            Sample2Found = False
            For i = UBound(Samples) To 0 Step -1
                If Samples(i).Volume > 0 Then
                    Select Case True
                        Case Samples(i).Conc <= ConcTarget And Samples(i).Conc >= Samples(Sample1).Conc
                            ' closest less concentrate sample
                            Sample1 = i
                            Sample1Found = True
                        Case Samples(i).Conc >= ConcTarget And Samples(i).Conc <= Samples(Sample2).Conc
                            ' closest more concentrate sample
                            Sample2 = i
                            Sample2Found = True
                    End Select
                End If
            Next

            ' check if necessary samples are available
            If Not (Sample1Found And Sample2Found) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If

        ' calculate delta for chosen samples
        ConcDelta = Samples(Sample2).Conc - Samples(Sample1).Conc
        ConcDelta1 = ConcTarget - Samples(Sample1).Conc
        ConcDelta2 = Samples(Sample2).Conc - ConcTarget

        ' calculate volumes
        Volume1 = (VolumeTarget - VolumeTotal) * ConcDelta2 / ConcDelta
        Volume2 = (VolumeTarget - VolumeTotal) * ConcDelta1 / ConcDelta
        VolumeMix = Volume1 + Volume2

        ' check if volumes are enough and reduce to available volume
        Select Case True
            Case Volume1 > Samples(Sample1).Volume ' sample 1 not enough
                Volume1 = Samples(Sample1).Volume
                VolumeMix = Volume1 * ConcDelta / ConcDelta2
                Volume2 = VolumeMix * ConcDelta1 / ConcDelta
                If Volume2 > Samples(Sample2).Volume Then ' sample 2 not enough
                    Volume2 = Samples(Sample2).Volume
                    VolumeMix = Volume2 * ConcDelta / ConcDelta1
                    Volume1 = VolumeMix * ConcDelta2 / ConcDelta
                End If
            Case Volume2 > Samples(Sample2).Volume ' sample 2 not enough
                Volume2 = Samples(Sample2).Volume
                VolumeMix = Volume2 * ConcDelta / ConcDelta1
                Volume1 = VolumeMix * ConcDelta2 / ConcDelta
                If Volume1 > Samples(Sample1).Volume Then ' sample 1 not enough
                    Volume1 = Samples(Sample1).Volume
                    VolumeMix = Volume1 * ConcDelta / ConcDelta2
                    Volume2 = VolumeMix * ConcDelta1 / ConcDelta
                End If
        End Select

        ' change available volumes
        Samples(Sample1).Volume = Samples(Sample1).Volume - Volume1
        Samples(Sample2).Volume = Samples(Sample2).Volume - Volume2

        ' check if target volume has been mixed
        VolumeTotal = VolumeTotal + VolumeMix
        If VolumeTotal = VolumeTarget Then Exit Do

    Loop

    ' results output
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To UBound(Samples)
            .Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Samples(i).Initial - Samples(i).Volume
        Next
        .Cells(2, 5).Value = VolumeTotal
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I populated `Sheet1` with source data:

[image: initial data]

After that `Worksheet_Change` event is fired, and results are populated in "To be mixed" column and "Actual volume" cell. Any changes on the sheet give results immediately:

[image: results]

If any zero concentration sample is available then it will be used first of all:

[image: zero concentration sample]

Comment: @CPowers, I've reworked the algorithm to output results directly to the sheet, check the code.

Comment: Wow this is excellent thank you very much. Works very well, except if I were to add say 20 samples, I would like to edit it so a max of only say 2-3 samples would need to be combined to be mixed. How would I limit number of samples that are chosen?

Comment: Or I can add in a row at the top to have a large volume, but 0 concentration to get to the desired total volume, but not add any more to concentration.

Comment: @CPowers, the algorithm computes the most optimal and frugal samples ratio (only by volume, since there is no cost per sample information). It starts with two samples only. More volume you need - more samples are in use. If you want to limit the number of samples (or if you think something works wrong), please edit you question, and add screenshot showing an example of excel worksheet, manually populated with correct values you want, and I will modify the algorithm to make it work such way.

Comment: @CPowers, regarding a large volume of zero concentration, going that way you allow to get to the desired total volume by dilution, which results in concentration decrease.

Comment: Thanks- I think if sample 1 were changed to 0 concentration, and adjust the volume to a smaller amount that is always added to the target volume, say 100-5000, that would work. The 'Do' loop would need to be changed to start at row 3, and always automatically add the value from sample 1 (row 2) to the target volume and concentration(in the initial data retrieval). You are correct, I understand it would dilute the final concentration, but using multiple samples is not avoidable as I thought.

Comment: @CPowers, do I right understand that the only change to be done to the algorithm  is to use a zero concentration sample as much as possible?

Comment: Not necessarily as much as possible, there will only be 1 sample with 0 concentration, which can always be sample 1. For sample 1 I want to be able to enter an amount -say 2000- with a concentration of 0, and have that amount always added to the final target volume and concentration. The "To be mixed" value for sample 1 should be fixed as the same value that is entered in the volume cell. Then samples 2-end will be added at a variable amount and can keep the same code.

Comment: @CPowers, the code can't be kept the same for approach you described, since it implies start from zero concentration. But current algorithm works with constant target concentration from first iteration to last. Could you please explane what is the main idea of setting the certain amount of zero concentrstion sample? Why not to make flexible algorithm which would calculate it itself?

Comment: the concentration would still start at 0-but the volume will start at however much is input in B2/D2. I want to be able to add a specific amount of 0 concentration to the final sample for dilution, and thought it would be easiest to put it for the first sample, and start the code for row 3 and below. With the current code-there is no way to add a sample with 0 concentration to dilute, because it looks for samples with concentration to get to the target concentration. Is it difficult to start the code at row 3, with the initial volume being whatever is input for volume in sample 1?

Comment: @CPowers, again, note - current algorithm works with constant target concentration, it doesn't start at 0 concentration.

Comment: SO I think for VolumeTarget would just need to be Cells(2,6).Value-Cells(2,2).Value

Comment: Right, the target concentration will stay the same, the final sample will just be diluted initially with the first sample having 0 concentration. I believe the current code should be able to still achieve the desired target concentration, it will just select samples with slightly higher concentration to compensate for the initial volume added that has 0 concentration.

Comment: @CPowers, why don't you want the amount of 0 concentration sample to be computed by algorithm?

Comment: I'm not sure how it would be-I assume its easier to just use whatever is input. Its my understanding the algorithm selects the samples with concentration closest to the target concentration and adds them. If there is a sample with 0 concentration, wouldn't it never be added by the algorithm because according to the algorithm it adds no value to get to the target concentration?

Comment: @CPowers, IMO the easiest way is to add one additional check at the begin of iteration: if there is any 0 concentration volume available then it must be the first sample, and the second sample must be the one having highest concentration. That is why I'm trying to avoid extra given parameter.

Comment: Yes I agree, so it would see if there is any 0 concentration, and if there is it is added automatically. I'm not sure why the second sample would need to be the one with the highest concentration though-can't it just loop through the algorithm as it does now after the first sample is automatically added?

Comment: @CPowers, the second sample need to be the one with the highest concentration to reduce the volume in use of any samples having greater than zero concentration.

Comment: @CPowers, I've added few lines of code that give mentioned functionality, please check.

Comment: With a quick test it looks like it works GREAT! Thank you very much for your insight and kind generosity to help. It is much appreciated.